# Local development without using google service account key

Tags: google-cloud-platform, minikube

Is it possible to do local development without using google service account key in minikube.
Currently I have a service account key which I use to authenticate google services inside the pod in minikube.

I want to avoid using service account key and instead use IAM role.

```
Iam User - XXX@XX.com 
I am given required role/permission to this iam user.
```

After using gcloud auth login,  I can access the google services. Is it possible to do similar way  in k8s/minikube pods.

Comment: In effect, `gcloud auth login` generates an OAuth token in a similar way to a service account but with different security and auditing. The important detail is what do you want to do after you have a token. Google prefers (and enforces via quotas) API calls with user credentials (gcloud auth login). Edit your question with additional details.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you can cheat. ***Use it only for development environment, never in production***

- Firstly, locate your own user credentials created with the `gcloud auth application-default login`. The created file is

  - on linux `~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json`
  - on windows `%appdata%\gcloud\application_default_credentials.json`
- Then mount this file (or copy it) into minikube
- You can define your `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env var to reference this file.

That's all, your credential will be used! Be careful, there is some limitation, I [wrote an article on this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/the-2-limits-of-iam-service-on-google-cloud-7db213277d9c)

Comment: Thanks a lots, I was looking for something like this.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mixing things up. You can never use a key instead of a role. In most cases, you need both of them. You need a key to authenticate to the Google Cloud Platform. And you need a certain IAM role to access services within GCP. Authentication means confirming your own identity, whereas authorization means being allowed access to the system.

In your specific case, I think you are referring to the process of letting your application/code use your own identity to authentication to the Google Cloud Platform. There are 2 possibilities here:

1. Download a service account key file, which is prone to security leaks, because those key files are not rotated by themselves.
2. As @guillaume blaquiere explains below, you could also generate a key file using your own identity. The specifics about this are well explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login) and [here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/the-2-limits-of-iam-service-on-google-cloud-7db213277d9c). For local development, this is preferred over the other option.

If you want to know how your SDK works with key files, I would recommend you take a look inside the SDK for the programming language you are using. There is always be a reference to `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. This is the location of the key file you are using.

Comment: I disagree. Have a look to my answer, what do you think?

Comment: Yep I agree! Never knew that this was possible.